# Laravel 8 Heroku 404 on Apache

Tags: heroku, apache2, laravel-8, procfile

I created a new Laravel 8 project to test on Heroku; I set the procfile as the manual.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel

To use Apache, I set the Procfile

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

The welcome page shows the following.

> 404 | not found

Comment: Does the welcome page work on your local development environment?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why but in laravel 8 if either one of these is missing from your Config Vars on heroku you will get that error.

There are two solution I found for this.
Set APP_URL to the heroku url or set your APP_ENV to local.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem rely on config vars, basically this config vars bellow has to be set.

```
APP_DEBUG : true
APP_ENV : production
APP_KEY : "your app key"
APP_NAME : Laravel
APP_URL : "the url of your application"
```